# Need help calculating a percentage of GC content in a DNA sequence

Tags: python-3.x

I know this is probably really simple but I just need to add something to this code to calculate the percent of GC content in a sequence of DNA.  What is the easiest way to add this?

```
#!/cygdrive/c/Python34/Python
#This program takes a DNA sequence (without checking) and shows its length,
#individual base composition (the percent of each kind of base), and GC content
#(also as a percent) of the user supplied sequence.

DNASeq = "ACGT"
DNASeq = input ("Enter a DNA sequence: ")
DNASeq = DNASeq.upper() #Convert to uppercase for .count() function
DNASeq = DNASeq.replace(" ","") #Remove spaces

print("Sequence:", DNASeq)

SeqLength = float(len(DNASeq))

print("Sequence Length:", SeqLength)
BaseList = "ACGT"
for Base in BaseList:
    Percent = 100 * DNASeq.count(Base) / SeqLength
    print("%s: %4.1f" % (Base,Percent))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
gCount = DNASeq.count('G')
cCount = DNASeq.count('C')
gcContent = round((gCount + cCount) / SeqLength, 4)
print(gcContent)
```